# Job application cap?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

When applying to jobs, after a few (2, 3) submissions the job listing gets locked to the jobs on the first page (only the first jobs after a search appear, something like:

[image].

This is the end of the list; in order to see more jobs a new search has to be made).

How can I keep all search results for specific job filters (location/frameworks) whilst applying?